# imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: ) won't update a second time

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, ciimage

Case: I have a UISwitch button in view. When switch is off, the imageView will display a QRCode image generated from a string. When on, it will display a barcode image generated from string. I copied the QRCode and barcode generation functions from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/ and **they are working fine**.

**The problem is the imageView displays the generated image only for the first time**. When switching between QRCode and barcode, the imageView won't update anymore. I am 100% sure the UISwitch is working, the functions are called and returning the generated image. I have tested multiple times with break points and printing, the functions are not returning nil or empty images.

**Here is QRCode generation code**

```
func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)

        if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
            return UIImage(ciImage: output) //<== it always returns this
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Here is barcode generation code**

```
func generateBarcode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)

        if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
            return UIImage(ciImage: output) //<== it always returns this
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Here is how I switch between QRCode and barcode** and the logic is correct

```
func toggleBarcode(isBarcode : Bool) {
    if isBarcode {
        qrImageView.image = generateBarcode(from: "Hacking with Swift")
    } else {
        qrImageView.image = generateQRCode(from: "Hacking with Swift")
    }
}
```

When testing with something like

```
qrImageView.image = UIImage(named: "myimage")
```

it works everytime.

**The imageView won't just update with UIImage(ciImage: )**

I even tested with a few different versions of QR and barcode generation codes they all don't update the imageView for a second time.

I tried

```
qrImageView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

but no luck.

Comment: Can you share the logic in your `switch` function where you most probably call `toggleBarcode` just so we can rule out logic errors.

Comment: Using `UIImage(ciImage:)` to generate an image that can be displayed in a UIImageView was _always_ wrong. I don't know why it _ever_ worked, even the first time; you were just lucky, I guess. You have to _render_ the CIImage to get a UIImage.

Comment: @ShawnFrank the logic is correct no doubt. The first answer got it working. The thing is to create a CGImage from filter's output image and create a UIImage from that CGImage. Not create UIImage from CIImage.

Comment: Why should UIImage(ciImage:) not work? What would be the purpose of having that constructor if it is not meant to work? That makes no sense. The only use of UIImage is to display it in a UIImageView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick searching ... seems to be either a "bug" or a change...

Changing your generator code to this seems to correct the issue:

```
func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    let context = CIContext()

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
        
        if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
            if let retImg = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: retImg)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func generateBarcode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    let context = CIContext()

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
        
        if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
            if let retImg = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: retImg)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: To clarify for future readers, the key change here is creating and using a CIContext to create a CGImage, and then passing that into the UIImage instead of trying to create a UIImage from the CIImage directly.